# PHP Laravel custom guard error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error:

> Auth guard [accountant] is not defined.

This is my `config\auth.php` file

```
<?php



 return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],



'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
     'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'accountant' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'accountants',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
     'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'accountants' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Accountant::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],


'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
      'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'accountants' => [
        'provider' => 'accountants',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

The previous guard admin is working fine. But the accountant guard is throwing an error. What have I done incorrectly?

I have added the guard in the model as well

Comment: Maybe try a `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: That worked. Why does this happen? Does laravel cache the config file?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I've been bitten by it in the past too, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to clear the config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Here are the docs on configuration caching: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching

You may have previously run the `config:cache` command on your dev instance